# What are side effects of excessive kefir usage?

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition

I drink 1 liter of kefir a day because I find it extremely helpful to lose weight. But recently i heard that excessive usage might cause some diseases like podagra. However I was unable to find more information about it.

I'll post contents of it here. 1 liter kefir has:

+10x10^8 kob probiotic microorganisms

380kcal

970mg calcium

I'll skip carb, protein etc.

Ingredients: pastorized cow milk, water, kefir culture, probiotic microorganisms

Comment: Sweet lord that's a lot of kefir. If you sneezed while driving by a dairy farm, you'd probably turn all their milk into yogurt instantly.

Comment: :DD It is very very helpful so I drink it